# In Magento admin, product category, trying to do a duplicate when adding product produce error

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Warning: Illegal string offset 'new_file' in /var/www/vhosts/addalinkofcharm.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php on line 130

I do not know where even to start!  Can some one help? When I am adding product in the admin 1.4.0.1 there is option at the top  to add new, duplicate, reset, etc.  When I am adding product I select the duplicate, and the next will come up with all the same information except sku number. 
Now if I select the duplicate I get the error that I copied and pasted at the top.  Can anyone help?  Tadwestie

Answer (score 3):

there's no `new_file` index in the code at **app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php** at around line 135, which says `// For duplicating we need copy original images.`, so change the code::

```
// For duplicating we need copy original images.
$duplicate = array();
foreach ($value['images'] as &$image) {
     if (!isset($image['value_id'])) {
         continue;
     }
     $duplicate[$image['value_id']] = $this->_copyImage($image['file']);
     $newImages[$image['file']] = $duplicate[$image['value_id']];
}
```

to

```
$duplicate = array();
foreach ($value['images'] as &$image) {
     if (!isset($image['value_id'])) {
         continue;
     }
     $duplicate[$image['value_id']] = $this->_copyImage($image['file']);
     $newImages[$image['file']] = array();
     $newImages[$image['file']]['new_file'] = $duplicate[$image['value_id']];
     $newImages[$image['file']]['label'] = $image['label'];
}
```

Comment: Right, it seems fixed in 1.9 release, as seen there : https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/6135503a7bc8760a5be9b25db711b42fb18ea801/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php#L141